# Center content inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup. I am trying to have "Previous" all the way to the left, "Next" all the way to the right, and the numbers centered. I can't seem to get the numbers centered.

I tried `margin: 0 auto;` on `.numbers` to no avail. The closest I've come was to set the left margin on `.numbers` to something like 40%, but that seems hackish, because previous and next might not always be there, and there may be more or less than 4 numbers. I'm pretty flexible with the markup and css.

http://jsfiddle.net/dcsUc/15/

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="pagination">
        <div class="previous">Previous</div>
        <div class="numbers">
            <a href="#">1</a>
            <a href="#">2</a>
            <a href="#">3</a>
            <a href="#">4</a>
        </div>
        <div class="next">Next</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

And

```
#content {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.previous, .numbers {
    float: left;
}

.next {
    float: right;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
​
```

Comment: `.numbers { text-align: center; }`?

Comment: Nope - I just updated my post with a link to a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dcsUc/15/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `div.next` to before `div.numbers` in the markup, don't float `.numbers`, and apply `text-align: center` to `.numbers`.

[jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnJfP/) for those who don't think in css ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use "margin: 0px auto" you also have to set a width for the div.